# Pooling in Phoenix for OrientDB database

Tags: orientdb, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to use Phoenix/Elixir with OrientDB. I decided to build a little demo app to get a good understanding of it.

As database driver I will use [MarcoPolo](https://github.com/MyMedsAndMe/marco_polo) and not use Ecto at all. MarcoPolo is very low level (binary driver) and doesn't support pooling.

Do I have to use pooling? Does Phoenix have a way to deal with this? Or do I have to implement it myself using something like [Poolboy](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy)? Or something else?

I want to share the demo app to make life easier for others. So I want to go about it the right way. But maybe my approach is an overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MarcoPolo is a **non-blocking** client which means that when a process asks the MarcoPolo connection to send a command to OrientDB, MarcoPolo sends the command to OrientDB right away but then doesn't wait for the response (which it then receives as an Erlang message because it uses `:active` on `:gen_tcp`). What this means in practice is that a single MarcoPolo connection should be capable of handling several client processes, thus eliminating the need for pooling if your application doesn't have to handle lots of requests to OrientDB.

In case you want to use pooling, the simplest solution is probably poolboy as you already figured out. I have no OrientDB-specific setup but you can find some information on how to setup a pool of connections to a db in the documentation for [Redix](https://github.com/whatyouhide/redix) (a Redis client for Elixir). The principles are the same. [This](https://github.com/whatyouhide/redix#using-redix-in-the-real-world) is the section in the documentation for Redix that covers pooling.